# How to automatically run a R file from different directories?

Tags: r, bash

I have a file: `/mnt/d/main_folder/sub_folder1/ak33.R`.

The `ak33.R` file is in all the sub folders : 
`/mnt/d/main_folder/sub_folder2/ak33.R` 
`/mnt/d/main_folder/sub_folder3/ak33.R` 
`/mnt/d/main_folder/sub_folder4/ak33.R` 
`/mnt/d/main_folder/sub_folder5/ak33.R`

I wanted to run this ak33.R file from all these sub folders, how do i run using linux bash script using a for loop?

is there a command to read all the sub folders name and run them in for loop ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
for d in /mnt/d/main_folder/sub_folder*/; do
  Rscript "$d"ak33.R
done
```

If the sub folder number is just one character, you can use the `?` meta-character.

```
for d in /mnt/d/main_folder/sub_folder?/; do
  Rscript "$d"ak33.R
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following at my environment:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! -d /mnt/d/main_folder ]]
then
    echo "/mnt/d/main_folder not found"
else
    AK33FOUND=0
    for AK33FILES in $(find /mnt/d/main_folder -type f -name ak33.R 2>/dev/null)
    do
        if [[ -f "$AK33FILES" ]]
        then
            AK33FOUND=1
            if [[ -x "$AK33FILES" ]]
            then
                $AK33FILES
            else
                echo "$AK33FILES execute permission denied."
            fi
        fi
    done
    if [[ 0 -eq $AK33FOUND ]]
    then
        echo "No ak33.R files found at /mnt/d/main_folder"
    fi
fi
```

I like your name Grand father and Grand mother.

Comment: What's the sense of that last phrase? :-)

Comment: In Tamil Language: Thaatha referring Granfather. Paati referring Grand Mother. My grand father and grand mother died before 2013. However I like your name.